# Call Object by variable

Tags: c++, object, input

I'm relatively new to c++ so please excuse me if i mess up some terms...

My simplified problem is the following:

I have a class called `Contact`.

The definition is like this:

```
class Contact
{
private:
    int id;      
public:
    Contact(void);
    Contact(int);
    int returnContact(void);
};
```

And in Contact.cpp

```
  Contact::Contact(void)
    {
    }
    Contact::Contact(int setId)
    {
       id = setId
    }
    int Contact::returnContact(void)
    {
       return id;
    }
```

Now this works perfectly alright...

Now in my main.cpp file i define 2 Contacts:

```
Contact marc(0);
Contact philippe(1);
```

**What I want to do:**
Wait for an input and if the input is marc, print 0 (the id) and if the input is philippe, print 1.

**What I tried to do:**

```
while (true) {
        string tempword = "";

        cin >> tempword;
    cout << tempword.Contact::returnContact();
    }
```

Obviously that doesn't work, but does anyone know a good solution to get this working?

Thank you very much, nxt191 aka Marc

Comment: You will probably use a std::map <std::string, Contact>, probably hidden inside a ContactManager class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to call a function on a string. Try adjusting your Contact classes method `returnContact` to take a string. `returnContact(const &string str);`

To fully get the functionality you want, you probably need to add another class called something like `ContactManager`.

You can add each contact and then ask the manager each time you get a string if it matches.

```
ContactManager manager;
manager.addContact(marc);
manager.addContact(tom);

// read in a name

manager.findContact(name);
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a contact manager class and register all contacts in it. In that class there shall be a find(...) function which shall take a string argument and returns an integer in your case. The contact manager ciuld be a singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

Your member functions work on the **objects** that you create.Here you try to work on a string not an object so it is wrong.What you can do is you can create a struct of contacts and put the private data as the part of the struct and then create a vector of that struct.In the loop you can search for a vector element which has the same name attribute that the user entered and then print the id attribute of that element.